# Upper Bound for $ \frac{x^x}{x!} $

Tags: real-analysis

I'm look for an upper bound for $\frac{x^x}{x!}$, one which is stronger, i.e. lower, than: $$ e^{\sum_{i=1}^{x-1}log{\frac{x}{i}}} $$
(which one can arrive at just by some basic algebraic manipulation).

Comment: Is $x$ a positive integer? Also there is something wrong with your summation. There is no $i$ inside and you never define $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From one of the forms of [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) you can get
$$
\frac{x^x}{x!}\le\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\,\pi\,x}}.
$$

Comment: More precisely, for $x>1$ we have $x!=(1+d(x))(x/e)^x\sqrt {2\pi x}$ where $|d(x)|<1/6x....$  And $d(x)$ never changes sign, but off the top of my head I don't recall whether it's always $+$ or always $-$.